# jquery :empty selector accounting for line breaks and whitespace

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

### Question:

I am trying to fire a `.click()` event if a `<ul></ul>` element has no DOM within it.

The thought process behind this code is, when the user clicks the `x` the item slides left, and then is `.remove()` from the DOM. As a result of my beautifully whitespaced HTML, its leaving line breaks and spacing within the `ul` still. As such i can't get the `if()` statement to function properly.

Even by using `$.trim()` and then comparing it still won't fire the `.click()` event.

### Picture Of The HTML

[image]

### HTML

```
    <div class="btn-group pull-right nav-notice">
      <span class="badge badge-info nav-notice-button">8</span>
      <div class="notice-container">
        <span class="notice-arrow"></span>
        <ul class="notice-container-list">
          <li><span class="label label-warning">Warning</span><span class="notice-message">Warning 12315125</span><i class="notice-remove icon-remove-circle"></i></li>
          <li><span class="label label-success">success</span><span class="notice-message">Warning 12315125</span><i class="notice-remove icon-remove-circle"></i></li>
          <li><span class="label label-important">important</span><span class="notice-message">Warning 12315125</span><i class="notice-remove icon-remove-circle"></i></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
```

### jQuery

```
//live(), looking for past/present DOM
$('.notice-remove').live( "click", function(){
    //no double dipping!
    $this = $(this);
    //Hide the x item, improves the animation a bit
    $this.hide();
    //animate the width of the li, to give it a slideoff effect
    //when the animate completes, remove the element from the DOM
    $this.parent('li').animate({
        width: "0"
    }, 'fast', '',
    function(){
        $(this).remove();
    });
    //get the html contents of the ul element
    var str = $('.notice-container-list').html();
    //trim the contents of the ul, and if they are exactly empty
    //fire the click event to close the container
    if( $.trim(str) === "" ){
        log('Closing the Notice');
        $('.nav-notice-button').click();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt it will work this way. See, you're checking the element right after you declare some animate functionality for it. But that function will not be called immediately - that's the whole point of animate()! And this, it turn, means that when you check `<ul>` contents, it's still not empty.

Use the following technique instead: check how many elements are left in `<ul>` *when removing* `<li>`; if there's none of them, remove the `<ul>` itself:

```
$this.parent('li').animate({
        width: "0"
    }, 'fast', '',
    function(){
        var $li = $(this);
        if (! $li.siblings().length) {
           $li.parent().remove();
        }
        else {
           $li.remove();
        }
    });
```

Here's a working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mtrbF/) (had to put something texty in `<i></i>`, cannot use your css' icons). For the same reasons I used simple `.parent().remove()` instead of triggering the `$('.nav-notice-button').click()`, as I don't know what should be done with that click. )

Answer (score 0):

It's not better to simply check if `.notice-container-list` has zero children, instead of checking its `.html()`?